# Ressources relative path formatting

Tags: html, url, relative-path

I would like to know if using ./ at the start of a relative path in HTML impact the way the browser loads it or if it is just redundant ?

And if it is redundant, which one is better to use ?

```
<link href='./css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or

```
<link href='css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the href's access the same css file which is present in css folder and it won't result in any issues.
The reason why we normally prefer 1st href is for readability purpose.
It actually says to fetch the file from folder named CSS which is inside root directory.

While using 1st href we need to  little bit careful while specifying dot.

Only single dot should be specified if we wan't to access files from sub folder.

If we want to access files from parent folder then 2 dots should be specified.

e.g. link href = "../test.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'

Here we are trying to access test.css file which is present in root folder while the HTML page was rendered from folder1 which is a sub folder in root.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is redundant.

With relative paths, the browser will look for the location of the file *relative* to the page where the link appears. Since `./` refers to the directory where the working file is in (in this case, the `html` document), we can say both point to the same location - it's redundant.